# iFrame in UpdatePanel not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I'm trying to update the source of an iFrame when a button is clicked on the page. However, nothing seems to be happening...

**.ASPX:**

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="accountInfo">
                    <p class="submitButton">
                        <asp:Button ID="ValidateButton" runat="server" Text="Validate" OnClick="SubmitSponsor" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <iframe runat="server" id="PayPalFrame" height="150px" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
    protected void SubmitSponsor(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var driver = new Driver();
        var isvalid = driver.IsAppValid(URL.Text, APILINK, Connstring);

        if (isvalid)
        {
            PayPalFrame.Attributes.Add("src", "http://www.google.com");
            URLInvalid.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

I've also tried:
`PayPalFrame.Attributes["src"] = "http://www.google.com";` and still nothing.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint inside of `SubmitSponsor` does it get hit?

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with update panels, but don't you have to indicate what buttons will trigger a panel update and re-render?

Comment: @DaveZych yes, it goes through every command inside SubmitSponsor just fine.

Comment: @AnnL. no, it works fine for anything else I've tried other than updating the src attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code, and it works in a sample project:

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="accountInfo">
                <p class="submitButton">
                    <asp:Button ID="ValidateButton" runat="server" Text="Validate" OnClick="SubmitSponsor" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <iframe runat="server" id="PayPalFrame" height="150px" width="100%" frameborder="0">
            </iframe>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class UpdatePanelIFrameTester : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void SubmitSponsor(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isvalid = true;
        if (isvalid)
        {
            PayPalFrame.Attributes.Add("src", "http://www.ironworks.com");
        }
    }
}
```

I would inspect your code and ensure nothing is causing your page to refresh/perform a full postback (I changed the URL as google will not allow you to view it in an iframe under standard conditions).

Comment: Damn. I feel a little stupid now. It's due to the fact I was using Google for my testing. Since the iFrame was not showing anything, and when I viewed the source of the page, the src tag was not added, I assumed it was not working. I changed it to a different URL and it worked as expected. *note - even after it worked as intended, viewing the page source still did not show the updated "src" attribute on the iFrame tag, but that's ok. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem, glad you got it working.  Just as a future note, you won't really see most postback-related changes when you click "viewsource" on a browser.  If you would like to see what's currently displayed, using developer tools/firebug is the way to go.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to *remove* the src attribute and then re-add it, for this to work.  Not sure why this is, but I remember doing it the last time I worked with update panels.  Perhaps it's because the src attribute always already exists?

Anyway, here's some sample code:  [how to change the src attribute in iframe](http://forums.asp.net/t/1838282.aspx/1).

Comment: That's all well and good, however, if you look at my code above, an "src" attribute does not exist yet. So, removing it, in theory, does nothing.

Comment: After clicking the button, if you view the page source in your browser is there a src attribute set?

Comment: @r584  I would urge you to try it anyway, see if it works.  If it doesn't, I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: @DaveZych nope, src attribute does not show up in the source when i view it afterwards.